# How to List Entries from Google Sheet Column Range in HTML Table?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, html-table

I am currently using the following code to pull PO Number entries from column A in my Google Sheet tab named 'POHistory'.  The problem is, my entries are not listing out in vertical fashion in the HTML UI.  Instead, they are populating left to right.  Can you help fix?

UPDATED APPS SCRIPT:

```
function Review() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('orderHistory').evaluate();
  html.setHeight(600).setWidth(800);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Order History');
}

function htmlOrders() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("POHistory");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += "<tr>";
   for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
    optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][j] + "</td>";
  };
  optionsHTML += "</tr>";
  return optionsHTML;{
}
```

UPDATED HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

 td, th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>PO Number</th>
    <th>Vendor</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
   <?!= htmlOrders(); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each of your options is added in a row, but you also insert this entire output into a single row. Remove the `<tr>` and `</tr>` that bound `<?!= htmlOrders(); ?>`

Comment: Thank you , Tehhowch.  I just tried that, and now all 3 of my entries are appearing in one cell just above the table header row.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Add the relevant new snippet to the bottom of your post so we can see exactly how you structure the client document. Also include the client-side evaluated HTML bit (use F12 to open the browser console and use the element picker to find the table quickly

Comment: Tehhowch - I've added the updated HTML code to the above post.  Let me know what you see as errant.  Thank you so much!

Comment: And the client-side HTML?

Comment: I've updated the above post to reflect the latest update I've made to my APPS SCRIPT portion of the code in the file I am working with.

Comment: Am I missing something that you'd need to see, Tehhowch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually to build a table from a spreadsheet range requires two loops, one for rows(`<tr>`) another for cells (`<td>`). Assuming that the table should have the same shape (rows and columns) than the data on the spreadsheet something like the following should work:

```
var tableData = '';
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  tableData += '<tr>';
  for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
    tableData += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>';
  }
  tableData += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I think the `<td>` bits may be in the `data[i][0]` portion of the `htmlOutput()` function - this is why I asked to see the client-side HTML as well in my comment above

Comment: @tehhowch : To be certain about that the OP should share a source data sample.